# How to add 1 subscriber to multiple MailWizz (with different APIs and domains)?

Tags: php, mysql, api, email, web-development-server

I bought MailWizz, it's excellent. And the API is very easy to use:

https://github.com/twisted1919/mailwizz-php-sdk

https://api-docs.mailwizz.com/#subscribers-create

And what I need is to add this single subscriber to 2 different APIs, in 2 different domains. But I don't know how to do it, because I have to use only 1 setup.php file.

I simply created my HTML newsletter form with the name and email fields and directed to the **save.php** file with the following code:

```
<?php
// require the setup which has registered the autoloader
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/setup.php';

// CREATE THE ENDPOINT
$endpoint = new MailWizzApi_Endpoint_ListSubscribers();

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    // CREATE / UPDATE EXISTING SUBSCRIBER
    $response = $endpoint->createUpdate('id-my-list', array(
        'EMAIL'    => isset($_POST['EMAIL']) ? $_POST['EMAIL'] : null,
        'FNAME'    => isset($_POST['FNAME']) ? $_POST['FNAME'] : null
    ));
}
?>
```

**setup.php**

```
<?php// require the autoloader class if you haven't used composer to install the package
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/MailWizzApi/Autoloader.php';

// register the autoloader if you haven't used composer to install the package
MailWizzApi_Autoloader::register();

// configuration object
$config = new MailWizzApi_Config(array(
    'apiUrl'        => 'https://site1.com/mailwizz/api/',
    'publicKey'     => '0000000',
    'privateKey'    => '11111111',

    // components
    'components' => array(
        'cache' => array(
            'class'     => 'MailWizzApi_Cache_File',
            'filesPath' => dirname(__FILE__) . '/MailWizzApi/Cache/data/cache', // make sure it is writable by webserver
        )
    ),
));

// now inject the configuration and we are ready to make api calls
MailWizzApi_Base::setConfig($config);

// start UTC
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
?>
```

I have 2 API

```
'apiUrl' => 'https://site1.com/mailwizz/api/',
'publicKey' => '0000000',
'privateKey' => '11111111',

and
'apiUrl' => 'https://other-site2.com/mailwizz-new/api/',
'publicKey' => '22222222',
'privateKey' => '333333333',
```

Thanks.

Comment: for site1 is working perfectly. but I don't know how to save it on site2 either, because it is a different api, a different domain in setup.php and in the save.php file it will be a different "id-my-list" (id-my-list1 and id-my-list2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you:

```
    <?php

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/MailWizzApi/Autoloader.php';

// register the autoloader if you haven't used composer to install the package
MailWizzApi_Autoloader::register();

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$sites = [
    [
        'list_uid' => 'xxx',
        'config' => [
            'apiUrl'        => 'https://site1.com/mailwizz/api/',
            'publicKey'     => '0000000',
            'privateKey'    => '11111111',
        ]
    ],
    [
        'list_uid' => 'xxx',
        'config' => [
            'apiUrl'        => 'https://other-site2.com/mailwizz-new/api/',
            'publicKey'     => '22222222',
            'privateKey'    => '333333333',
        ]
    ]
];

foreach ($sites as $site) {

    $config = new MailWizzApi_Config($site['config']);

    MailWizzApi_Base::setConfig($config);

    $endpoint = new MailWizzApi_Endpoint_ListSubscribers();

    $response = $endpoint->createUpdate($site['list_uid'], array(
        'EMAIL'    => isset($_POST['EMAIL']) ? $_POST['EMAIL'] : '',
        'FNAME'    => isset($_POST['FNAME']) ? $_POST['FNAME'] : ''
    ));

}
```

While the examples use a `setup.php` file, it does not mean you have to use that as well. That's just an example.

Comment: Thank you!
Perfect, you're right, great solution. The only problem is that I have 2 different list ids (id-my-list1 and id-my-list2), can I put this variable inside the array $sites?
$response = $endpoint->createUpdate('id-my-list'

Comment: Thank you Twist! Now that I saw it was you, the user supporting me. With this new solution I will buy more versions of MailWizz at CodeCanyon to install on my clients!
Thank you very much and congratulations for the excellent system